# Set icon app for all iphone's and ipad's series

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, icons

I'm facing a problem with xcode. I created an icon (720x720) with Gimp. I found this site https://makeappicon.com/ that create the relative icon for a part of the iphone's and ipad's. It generate a folder with the images and a file called "Contents.json". The content of this file is:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "60x60",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "size" : "60x60",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "filename" : "Icon-40.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "76x76",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "filename" : "Icon-76.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "76x76",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-76@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "size" : "83.5x83.5",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-83.5@2x.png"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "makeappicon"
  }
}
```

With my iPhone 5s iOS 9.2 it works fine, that means the icon is set properly, but with my iPhone 3gs iOS 6.1.6 the icon is not set. What is missing in this file? Logically I can't have all iPhone's devices and iPad's devices. What miss also in the file, to match all devices from Apple (iPhone and iPad)? My app MUST support iOS 6.1 and iPhone 3gs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need 57x57.  Create that size and add Icon-57.png to your list.   (along with 2x).